# how to check attribute in xslt that input type is single select or multiple select

Tags: xslt

i wants to check attribute of input type is single select or multiple select in xslt , how to get attribute mselect & test the expression for it, if i have get the attribute mselect then i 'll append the new css class else default layout are displayed my code is below .

i have field which is manage by administrator if administrator set that field to single select then it displayed simple select box or if administrator set it to multiple select then it display multiple select input , but on both option applying same html structure but i want it to different.

```
<!-- select HTML code -->

<div class="controls category">
    <label>
        <select style="width: 250px;" class="cattest" id="field_category" name="field_category">
            <option value="">Select Category</option>
            <option value="36" disabled="disabled">- East Perth Cemetery</option>
            <option value="37">-- Genealogical (people)</option>
            <option value="38">-- Architectural (monuments)</option>
        </select>

        <span class="hide message-lightbulb" id="field_category-message">
            <i class="icon-lightbulb"></i>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>

<!-- mselect HTML code -->

<div class="controls category">
    <label>
        <select style="width: 250px; height: 100px" class="cattest" id="field_category" multiple="multiple" name="field_category[]">
            <option value="36" disabled="disabled">- East Perth Cemetery</option>
            <option value="37">-- Genealogical (people)</option>
            <option value="38">-- Architectural (monuments)</option>
        </select>
        <span class="hide message-lightbulb" id="field_category-message">
            <i class="icon-lightbulb"></i>
        </span>
   </label>
</div>
```

and i want it like :

```
<!-- select HTML code -->

<div class="controls category">
    <label>
        <select style="width: 250px;" class="cattest" id="field_category" name="field_category">
            <option value="">Select Category</option>
            <option value="36" disabled="disabled">- East Perth Cemetery</option>
            <option value="37">-- Genealogical (people)</option>
            <option value="38">-- Architectural (monuments)</option>
        </select>

        <span class="hide message-lightbulb" id="field_category-message">
            <i class="icon-lightbulb"></i>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>

<!-- mselect HTML code -->

<div class="controls category">

        <select style="width: 250px; height: 100px" class="cattest" id="field_category" multiple="multiple" name="field_category[]">
            <option value="36" disabled="disabled">- East Perth Cemetery</option>
            <option value="37">-- Genealogical (people)</option>
            <option value="38">-- Architectural (monuments)</option>
        </select>
        <span class="hide message-lightbulb" id="field_category-message">
            <i class="icon-lightbulb"></i>
        </span>

</div>
```

**and it's xslt code is :**

```
<xsl:if test="count( /search/fields/* ) &gt; 3">

                    <div id="SPExtSearch">
                        <xsl:for-each select="fields/*">
                            <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 3">
                            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>    
                            <xsl:variable name="fieldId" select="name(.)" />
                            <xsl:variable name="description" select="description" />
                            <xsl:variable name="fldalias" select="substring(name(.),1,9)"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="ftype" select="@type" />   
                            <xsl:variable name="fstyle" select="width" /> 

                            <xsl:variable name="title">
                                <!--  <xsl:value-of select="@id" />-->
                                <xsl:value-of select="php:function('SobiPro::Csm', @id)" />
                            </xsl:variable>

                            <xsl:if test="$title = 1">
                                <div class="control-group {$fieldId} {$fldalias}">

                                <label class="control-label payment-box" for="{name(.)}" >
                                    <xsl:value-of select="label"/>
                                </label>

                                <div class="controls {$ftype}">
                                    <label>                                    
                                        <xsl:if test="string-length( @suffix )">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="class">input-append</xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:if>                                
                                        <xsl:choose>                                            
                                            <xsl:when test="data/@escaped">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="data" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                                            </xsl:when>                                         
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <xsl:copy-of select="data/*" />
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>

                                        <xsl:choose>                                            
                                            <xsl:when test="string-length( @suffix )">
                                                <span class="add-on">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="@suffix" />
                                                </span>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:otherwise>                                         
                                                <span id="{$fieldId}-message" class="hide message-lightbulb">
                                                    <i class="icon-lightbulb" />
                                                </span>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                                </div>
                              </xsl:if>

                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </div>                   

            <div class="clearfix" />

                </xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the XLST code

```
<div class="controls {$ftype}">
 <label>      
    ... code ...
 </label>
</div>
```

With something like:

```
 <div class="controls {$ftype}">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="is mselect condition">
          <label><xsl:call-template name="create-select" /></label>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:call-template name="create-select" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
   </xls:choose>
  </div>
```

Where the ...code... passed into the template "create-select".